# Owin 3rd party login with Google or Facebook redirect failed (/Account/ExternalLoginCallback not working) C# MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, authentication, owin

When we test our program in local server the 3rd party login works fine, but that's not the case when we publish it onto the actual server. When we use 3rd party login on actual server, it didn't work.

So far what we know is our server provider is using https while our IIS server setting is using http. Could this be the cause? If not, any idea what's the problem we are encountering?

Here is the URL when we are entering account on Facebook 3rd party login page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=569249369941462&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.8%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ipce.com.tw%252Fsignin-facebook%26state%3DwXOgKtgLeatXfqXP-Cv-Rc5EJu7AYiWQyqyN4bqtWfgZr6ncxzc9uerpXv4uSKZoSUQpWwO5AUt2YksiIP3q05GhjVUoT94kMZD5E57a2PgMaJT8oSrXh1K9lrH3g88DF0M2jtGX-DWJl-UJ66g_neu5xx1pGsIc3NBvblBjQfWM_rR6Vt8qB16GTCMqxSsQXhH4UXRDuQY5eBLSUKS7W0SRJMzDNClgMRT-VTZ7Gvv4oYTEAXnFG6qmh41o-xT5%26scope%3Demail%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D569249369941462%26ret%3Dlogin%26logger_id%3D2a07ffc7-acf8-ad97-0b9f-b45dcff38b39&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipce.com.tw%2Fsignin-facebook%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%3DwXOgKtgLeatXfqXP-Cv-Rc5EJu7AYiWQyqyN4bqtWfgZr6ncxzc9uerpXv4uSKZoSUQpWwO5AUt2YksiIP3q05GhjVUoT94kMZD5E57a2PgMaJT8oSrXh1K9lrH3g88DF0M2jtGX-DWJl-UJ66g_neu5xx1pGsIc3NBvblBjQfWM_rR6Vt8qB16GTCMqxSsQXhH4UXRDuQY5eBLSUKS7W0SRJMzDNClgMRT-VTZ7Gvv4oYTEAXnFG6qmh41o-xT5%23_%3D_&display=page&locale=zh_TW&logger_id=2a07ffc7-acf8-ad97-0b9f-b45dcff38b39
```

and this is the URL after we login, back to our home page but /Account/ExternalLoginCallback is not called

```
https://www.ipce.com.tw/?code=AQAUdHG-r1AxBOy1xkVm4sklkq-tBKn-9c_PAYqqpZmwiseTcKWAnTRJkoyeoZkiwReg_x7VSnMymQiWgqp0ZdnhlH1ypijH-FSyaca5BDCMJUS04x05CNVjrN5HvuRXdVJkv2OHwzqkTSWvkwC6S58nrRckIjroKjjGDqaWvldOt_0g8nFe_ZvLovj_hbdQs5SPE4M97CpPrm0ExudeEddEo1zn29RIMabS204kF445Hn73X90RTy7WpIqAINpcIIwK4XeAQMcoqoBQinaVRyjrNxjvKoAEXqBPBKKkdJn7u3bx94rFZXqHGGMJ6uth0rBSpDPJgtq0M1XMmYXfESjS&state=wXOgKtgLeatXfqXP-Cv-Rc5EJu7AYiWQyqyN4bqtWfgZr6ncxzc9uerpXv4uSKZoSUQpWwO5AUt2YksiIP3q05GhjVUoT94kMZD5E57a2PgMaJT8oSrXh1K9lrH3g88DF0M2jtGX-DWJl-UJ66g_neu5xx1pGsIc3NBvblBjQfWM_rR6Vt8qB16GTCMqxSsQXhH4UXRDuQY5eBLSUKS7W0SRJMzDNClgMRT-VTZ7Gvv4oYTEAXnFG6qmh41o-xT5#/_=_
```

I tried forcing http to https, but a server error 500 happened, I can't figure another way to fix the problem.

somebody help me please

**Try 1**

I set localhost server Route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "SigninFacebook",
     url: "signin-facebook",
     defaults: new { controller = "Member", action = "ExternalLoginCallback" }
);
```

It works! but it responded HTTP ERROR 500.

I tried applying the setting to actual server, well, nothing happened.
It still redirect to our home page, and ExternalLoginCallback still not called.
I doubt our actual server didn't get to signin-facebook Route.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it happens because you provide redirect_uri=localhost.

This parameter is used to redirect the browser page after successful 3rd party login to provide a auth code from Facebook to your server.

It works in your test environment because your webserver is local so browser can perform redirect to localhost.

But in production environment the real domain name should be used instead of localhost.

Comment: I have edited the post, change to actual URL, please review again, thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your redirect_url contains GET parameters (?state=... and so on) that makes your final request string a little bit odd. So try to simplify redirect_url request passing parameters as a part of URL path and convert them in controller using Route attribute:
 [Route("signin-facebook/{state}/{...}")]

Comment: I tried your advice, and I edited the post again. thanks!